# Add a custom iOS App Store developer icon

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I noticed that some apps have a custom icon displayed above the developer name:
[image]

I could not find any place in App Store Connect where to set this, is this something only certain developers have access to?

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do this? Have looked everywhere but no luck

Comment: No, unfortunately I did not find out